# Split only one the first separator and keep all

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have a df with column entries that look like this:

```
data = [['5-820.0g:2021-05-18T07:25, 5-986.x:2021-05-18T07:25', '5-820.00:2021-05-18T07:25, 5-986.x:2021-05-18T07:25'], ['5-820.00:2021-05-18T07:25, 5-986.x:2021-05-18T07:25', '5-820.00:2021-05-18T07:25, 5-986.x:2021-05-18T07:25']]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])
```

An I need them to split on the first ':' the 'T' and the ',' and expand them.

If I use the classical

```
df.column_name.str.split('[\:,T]', expand=True)
```

It is splitting by the second ':' too. How can I avoid that to get the wanted output:

```
data_2 = [['5-820.0g', '2021-05-18' ,'07:25' , '5-986.x', '2021-05-18' ,'07:25'], ['5-820.00', '2021-05-18' ,'07:25' , '5-986.x', '2021-05-18' ,'07:25']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6'])
df
```

Comment: One second, im changing it. Sorry

Comment: can you provide your desired output of example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not fully clear, but you can maybe restrict the split to the `:` that is preceded by a `d` or `f`:

```
df.column_name.str.split('(?:(?<=[df]):|[,T])', expand=True)
```

Or **not preceded by a digit**:

```
df.column_name.str.split('(?:(?<!\d):|[,T])', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
          0           1      2          3           4      5
0  5-784.0d  2021-03-29  10:15   5-784.0f  2021-03-29  10:15
```

##### updated example:

Splitting `:` if followed by a 4 digits year and `-`

```
df.stack().str.split(':(?=\d{4}-)|[,T]', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
                0           1      2          3           4      5
0 col_1  5-784.0d  2021-03-29  10:15   5-784.0f  2021-03-29   None
  col_2  5-784.0d  2021-03-29  10:15   5-784.0f  2021-03-29   None
1 col_1  5-820.00  2021-05-18  07:25    5-986.x  2021-05-18  07:25
  col_2  5-820.00  2021-05-18  07:25    5-986.x  2021-05-18  07:25
2 col_1  5-820.00  2021-05-18  07:25    5-986.x  2021-05-18  07:25
  col_2  5-820.00  2021-05-18  07:25    5-986.x  2021-05-18  07:25
```

Comment: Yes that should work! How can I change it to: followed by a "2"?

Comment: You can use `:(?=2)`, full pattern: `:(?=2)|[,T]`

Comment: It worked, but sometimes my time is 07:25, so it splits that one too. Maybe I can prepare a better df in my description, that can be replicated better.

Comment: Modified it, maybe you have any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tested my `(?:(?<!\d):|[,T])` suggestion above?

Comment: Yes, but I prepared a code example on the top and im my df there is not always a "df" preceded.

Comment: `(?:(?<!\d):|[,T])` doesn't check for d/f but for any non-digit, please try it first

Comment: tried it, but with this one: ```'5-820.00:2021-05-18T07:25,```it isnt working bc 0 is a digit.

Comment: OK, it looks like you always have a year after `:`, try my updated answer

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you for being so patient, even tho my fist example was very bad. It worked!!!